# TikZ: Shaded, Nested, Inverted Cones (Related Rates Diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, shading, shadows

I'm reading about related rates (differential calculus), and I'm currently working on the inverted cone water tank problem. In the textbook I'm reading, there exists this rather nice diagram of the situation.

[image]

I've messed around a bit with Ti*k*Z's fadings and shadings in the past and always found the interface difficult to say the least. Doing a diagram like this that appears to involve fadings and shadows and other messy elements is beyond any approach I can think of (hence, I have forgone posting an MWE).

**How can I recreate the cones in the diagram above?** I am confident that if the cones are done, I can finish the diagram. Note that I am not opposed to an answer involving LaTeX's other graphics-related packages, but Ti*k*Z is the only one I've looked into so far, so a bit more explaining and/or links probably wouldn't hurt if you go that route :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shading effects might be difficult to achieve using plain Ti*k*Z/PGFPlots. You are better off using [Asymptote](https://ctan.org/pkg/asymptote?lang=en) instead. However, I have written an Asymptote and Ti*k*Z/PGFPlots solutions.

### Asymptote Solution

Please note that I literally learned the basics of Asymptote overnight to come up with the solution (I have never used it before). It could improve, aesthetically speaking. The text in red is just there to show the coordinates used (which is found at the end of the code). Originally, I used [this](http://www.piprime.fr/files/asymptote/solids/fig0100.asy) as the starting point, credits should always be given :).

[image: Asymptote output]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asypictureB}

\begin{document}
    \begin{asypicture}{name=ConeDiagram}
        unitsize(1cm);
        import solids;
        settings.render = 0;
        
        currentprojection = orthographic(0, 180, -45, up = -Z); //view
        pen thick = linewidth(2pt);
        
        real r = 5;     // Radius of larger cone
        real h = 10;    // Height of larger cone
        // The next coordinates represents the larger cone
        triple origin = (0, 0, 0);
        triple coneCenter = (0, 0, h/2);
        triple coneTip = (0, 0, h);
        triple largerConeRadius=(r,0,0);
        
        // Creating the two cones
        revolution largeCone = cone(origin, r, h, axis = Z);
        revolution smallCone = cone(coneCenter, r/2, h/2, axis = Z);
        // Drawing the two cones on screen
        // Use the following for light options: Headlamp, Viewport, White or nolight.
        draw(surface(largeCone), surfacepen = white, light = Viewport);
        draw(surface(smallCone), surfacepen = lightgreen, light = Viewport);
        
        // Drawing the border around the smaller cone
        skeleton s;
        largeCone.transverse(
            s, reltime(largeCone.g, abs(coneCenter) / h), currentprojection
        );
        triple smallConeRadius = relpoint(
            largerConeRadius -- coneTip, abs(coneCenter) / h
        );
        draw(s.transverse.back, dashed + green + linewidth(1pt));
        draw(s.transverse.front, green + linewidth(1pt));
        
        // The radius lines (from the center of the cone to the edge)
        draw(
            L = Label("$5f(t)$", position = Relative(0.5), align = N, black), 
            origin -- largerConeRadius, white + thick
        );
        draw(
            L = Label("$x$", position=Relative(0.5), align = N, black), 
            coneCenter -- smallConeRadius, white + thick
        );
        
        // Vertical line through the middle of the cone
        draw(coneTip -- origin, yellow + thick);
        
        // Drawing bottom-right line in the diagram
        draw(coneTip -- (r + 1, 0, h), red + thick);
        triple smallConeVerticalLineBottomCoord=(r/2, 0, h);
        
        // Vertical line denoting the smaller cone
        triple smallConeVericalLineTop = (
            smallConeRadius.x + 0.5, smallConeRadius.y, smallConeRadius.z
        );
        triple smallConeVericalLineBottom = ((r / 2) + 0.5, 0, h);
        draw(
            L = Label(
                "$y$", align=(0, 0), position = MidPoint, 
                filltype = Fill(white), black
            ), 
            smallConeVericalLineBottom -- smallConeVericalLineTop, blue, Arrows3()
        );
        
        // Vertical line denoting the larger cone
        triple largeConeVericalLineTop = (
            largerConeRadius.x + 0.5, largerConeRadius.y, largerConeRadius.z
        );
        triple largeConeVericalLineBottom = (r + 0.5, 0, h);
        draw(
            L = Label(
                "$10(ft)$", align=(0, 0), position = MidPoint, 
                filltype = Fill(white), black
            ), 
            largeConeVericalLineBottom -- largeConeVericalLineTop, blue, Arrows3()
        );
        
        // The labels of the important coordinates used
        dot(Label("Origin", align = Z, red), origin);
        dot(Label("$AAA$", align = Z, red), smallConeRadius);
        dot(Label("$BBB$", align = Z, red), largerConeRadius);
        dot(Label("$CCC$", align = Z, red), coneCenter);
        dot(Label("$DDD$", align = Z, red), coneTip);
        dot(Label("$EEE$", align = N, red), smallConeVericalLineTop);
        dot(Label("$FFF$", align = Z, red), smallConeVericalLineBottom);
        dot(Label("$GGG$", align = N, red), largeConeVericalLineTop);
        dot(Label("$HHH$", align = Z, red), largeConeVericalLineBottom);
    \end{asypicture}
\end{document}
```

### Ti*k*Z solution

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  customTip/.tip={stealth[angle=0:4pt]Bar[sep=1pt,width=10pt]},
}
% Custom colours used
\definecolor{lightBlue}{rgb}{0.03, 0.91, 0.87}
\definecolor{darkBlue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.75, 1.0}

% Formula for the cone is copied from http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html (example 169)
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{22.5},
            hide axis, axis lines=center,
            clip=false,
            domain=0.0075:1, y domain=0:2*pi,
            xmin=-1.25, xmax=1.25,
            ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
            ymin=-1.25, ymax=1.25,
            samples=45  % The more samples, the sharper the diagram which takes longer to render
        ]
            % Larger cone 
            \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, 
                mesh/interior colormap={outerConeColourMap}{
                    color=(gray)                % bottom colour
                    color=(lightgray) 
                    color=(gray) 
                    color=(darkgray) 
                    color=(gray)                % top colour
                },
                mesh/interior colormap thresh=1
            ] ({x*cos(deg(y))}, {x*sin(deg(y))}, {x});
             % Smaller cone
            \addplot3 [surf, shader=interp, 
                mesh/interior colormap={innerConeColourMap}{
                    color=(darkBlue)    % bottom colour
                    color=(lightBlue)
                    color=(darkBlue)    % top colour
                },
                mesh/interior colormap thresh=1
                ] ({x/2*cos(deg(y))}, {x/2*sin(deg(y))}, {x/2});
            % Generating points to refer to later.
            \coordinate (origin) at (0, 0, 0);
            \coordinate (bottomConeLeft) at (0.05, 0, 0);
            \coordinate (middleConeLeft) at (0, 3, 0);
            \coordinate (topConeLeft) at (0, 6, 0);
            %
            \coordinate (bottomConeRight) at (1.25, 0, 0);
            \coordinate (middleConeRight) at (0.5, 3, 0);
            \coordinate (topConeRight) at (1, 6, 0);
            %
            % Horizontal line at the bottom of cone
            \draw[blue, very thick](bottomConeLeft) -- (bottomConeRight);
            % Horizontal line at the middle of cone
            \draw[yellow, very thick](middleConeLeft) -- 
            node[black, above, yshift=-2pt]{$x$}(middleConeRight);
            % Horizontal line at the top of cone
            \draw[green, thick](topConeLeft) -- node[black, above]{$5(ft)$}(topConeRight);
            % Vertical line in middle of cone
            \draw[red,very thick](origin) -- (0, 6.025, 0);         
            % Adding the vertical lines with arrow tips
            \draw[customTip-customTip, blue, thick]
            ([xshift=1em]middleConeRight) -- node[black, above, fill=white, pos=0.65]{$y$}
            ([xshift=1em]middleConeRight|-bottomConeRight);
            %
            \draw[customTip-customTip, blue, thick]
            ([xshift=1em]topConeRight) -- node[black, above, fill=white, pos=0.55]{$10(ft)$}
            ([xshift=1em]topConeRight|-bottomConeRight);
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just took a look at Asymptote -- looks very promising! Would you be able to write up a solution in it and/or explain how one might go about doing so?

Comment: @ShadyPuck, please see my edit.